# Using type of function pointer as template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write a template which gets the type of a functionpointer as templateargument and the corresponding functionpointer as a function argument, so as a simplyfied example I'm doing this right now:

```
int myfunc(int a)
{ return a; }

template<typename T, typename Func> struct Test
{
    typedef typeof(myfunc) Fun;
    static T MyFunc(T val, Func f)
    {
        return f(val);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    std::cout<<Test<int, typeof(myfunc)>::MyFunc(5, myfunc)<<std::endl;
}
```

However this code instantly crashes. If I change the type of f to `Fun` it works perfectly.
So what am I doing wrong and how can I get this to work?

I'm using mingw under windows vista if that behaviour in case that behaviour is compiler dependent.

Comment: typeof is not part of C++, so that doesn't even compile on my compiler

Comment: Compiles and runs perfectly here.

Comment: `typeof` is a GCC extension.  I assume it's not available on MSVC.

Comment: `decltype` isn't in the current version of C++, but is due in the next version. gcc generats the expected errors so long as it is in C++ mode (e.g. `-std=c++98`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need the `Test` class for this scenario, and Why use the `typeof` function here?

```
template< typename T, typename fT > 
T TestMyFunc( T t, fT f ) {
   return f(t);
};
```

will do, and no fiddling with function pointer types:

```
std::cout << TestMyFunc(5,myfunc) << std::endl;
```

The template arguments are deduced automatically for functions!

Answer (score 2):

`typeof` isn't valid C++, but if I replace your two lines involving them with these, then your code works fine with either `Fun` or `Func` in the definition of `MyFunc`.

```
typedef int (*Fun)(int);
```

and

```
std::cout<<Test<int, int(*)(int)>::MyFunc(5, myfunc)<<std::endl;
```